# LARAVEL 9: how to make and save data to database with multiple select dropdown form?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2, laravel-9, multiple-select-query

I'm making multiple select options in modals, but when I select only 1 option that can be selected, what's wrong with it? Please help.
this is Controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    $settingalokasi = New Settingalokasi;

    $settingalokasi->id_jeniscuti = $request->id_jeniscuti;
    $settingalokasi->tipe_alokasi = $request->tipe_alokasi;
    $settingalokasi->durasi       = $request->durasi;
    $settingalokasi->mode_alokasi = $request->mode_alokasi;
    $settingalokasi->departemen   = $request->departemen; 
    $settingalokasi['mode_karyawan']= json_encode($request->mode_karyawan);

    $settingalokasi->save();
    
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
  }
```

this is form formsetting.blade.php:, here I use select2 version 4.0.1:

```
{{-- FORM SETTING ALOKASI--}}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="newsetting" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newsetting" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="newsetting">Setting Alokasi Cuti</h4>
            </div>  

            @if ($errors->any()) 
                <div class="alert alert-danger show" role="alert">
                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br> 
                        <ul> 
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error) 
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li> 
                            @endforeach 
                        </ul> 
                </div> 
            @endif 
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="input" action="{{ route('setting_alokasi.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    @method('POST')
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm" id="jenicuti">
                                <label for="id_jeniscuti" class="col-form-label">Kategori Cuti</label>
                                <select name="id_jeniscuti" id="id_jeniscuti" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Pilih Kategori Cuti</option>
                                    @foreach ($jeniscuti as $data)
                                        <option value="{{ $data->id}}"
                                            @if ($data->id ==request()->id_jeniscuti)
                                            selected
                                            @endif
                                            >{{ $data->jenis_cuti }}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm">
                                <label for="tipe_alokasi" class="col-form-label">Tipe Alokasi</label>
                                <select name="tipe_alokasi" id="tipe_alokasi" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Pilih Tipe Alokasi</option>
                                    <option value="Reguler">Reguler</option>
                                    <option value="Aktual">Aktual</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="durasi" class="col-form-label">Durasi</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="durasi" placeholder="durasi" id="durasi">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm" id="modalokasi">
                                    <label for="mode_alokasi" class="col-form-label">Mode Alokasi</label>
                                    <select name="mode_alokasi" id="mode_alokasi" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Pilih Mode Alokasi</option>
                                        <option value="Berdasarkan Departemen">Berdasarkan Departemen</option>
                                        <option value="Berdasarkan Karyawan">Berdasarkan Karyawan</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm" id="mode_departemen">
                                <label for="departemen" class="col-form-label">Departemen</label>
                                <select name="departemen" id="departemen" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Pilih Departemen</option>
                                    <option value="KONVENSIONAL">KONVENSIONAL</option>
                                    <option value="KEUANGAN">KEUANGAN</option>
                                    <option value="TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI">TEKNOLOGI INFORMASI</option>
                                    <option value="HUMAN RESOURCE">HUMAN RESOURCE</option>
                                </select>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="form-group col-sm" id="mode_employee">
                                <label for="mode_karyawan" class="col-form-label">Karyawan</label>
                                <select id="mode_karyawan" name="mode_karyawan[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
                                    {{-- <option value=""> ----- Pilih -----</option> --}}
                                    <option value="L">Laki-laki</option>
                                    <option value="P">Perempuan</option>
                                    <option value="Sudah">Sudah Menikah</option>
                                    <option value="Belum">Belum Menikah</option>
                                    <option value=">= 1 Tahun">>= 1 Tahun</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="save">Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery  -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{{-- // Datatable init js  --}}
<script src="assets/pages/datatables.init.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

{{-- // Plugins Init js --}}
<script src="assets/pages/form-advanced.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#mode_departemen').prop("hidden", true);
        $('#mode_employee').prop("hidden", true);
    
        $('#modalokasi').on('change', function(a)
        {
            if(a.target.value== 'Berdasarkan Departemen')
            {
                $('#mode_departemen').prop("hidden", false);
                $('#mode_employee').prop("hidden", true);
            }
            if(a.target.value== 'Berdasarkan Karyawan')
            {
                $('#mode_departemen').prop("hidden", true);
                $('#mode_employee').prop("hidden", false);
            }
            
        });
    });
   
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mode_karyawan").select2();
    });
</script>
```

this is picture for ERROR:

[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kEqp.png)
[2nd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr2be.png)

help please, which part is wrong, today I'm just trying to solve this error and until now I haven't found a solution at all

Answer (score 0):

try change your jquery

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```